# Vb6 Sql update query

Tags: sql, vb6

what is wrong in this code i get syntax error from this query

ssql = "UPDATE karakter SET  lvl='" & Form1.Label7.Caption & "','" & hp = Form1.Label18.Caption & "','" & mp = Form1.Label17.Caption & "','" & para = Form1.Label19.Caption & "','" & yuzde = Form1.Label16.Caption & "'  WHERE id='" & Form1.Label5.Caption & "'"

Comment: Please edit your question and show what `ssql` looks like after variable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong positions for you quotes.

```
ssql = "UPDATE karakter SET  lvl='" & Form1.Label7.Caption & "', " & _
                             "hp ='" & Form1.Label18.Caption & "', " & _
                             "mp ='" & Form1.Label17.Caption & "', " & _
                             "para ='" & Form1.Label19.Caption & "', " & _
                             "yuzde ='" & Form1.Label16.Caption & "' " & _
       "WHERE id='" & Form1.Label5.Caption & "'"
```

I suggest to use the parameters instead of concatenation.

Comment: It is in case, when all of your columns of char/varchar data type. Else you must correct single quotes around the update values.

Comment: i did it in to my phpmyadmin all types are varchar